# How to take comma as text in comma separated text in python

Tags: python-2.7, split, user-input

Hi I'm new to python and I wanted to know how enter comma as text in comma separated string in  python

for eg

Text=raw_input("Enter the symbols").split(",")

Input:

A, b, c, d, e,",",f

Output:

["A","b","c","d",",","f"]

Comment: You want to enter it into comma separated data? Read it from comma separated data? Or both?

Comment: @conner.xyz I think he wants to have a comma in the field, which seems difficult to do given that commas are also the delimiters for values.

Comment: Yes...I want raw_input to take comma when input string is comma delimited

Comment: @Ares you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `split` statement, it literally matches the delimiter (`,` in this case).

Doing something like this takes proper parsing, e.g. using the csv module

```
import csv

Text = raw_input("Enter the symbols:")
reader = csv.reader([Text], delimiter=',')
symbols = next(reader)
print(symbols)
```

---

Update: when scanning for symbols, doubles and `""` are probably not valid.

For instance, `a,a,b,,","` would give `['a', 'a', 'b', '', ',']`

So this extension cleans symbols as well:

```
import csv

Text = raw_input("Enter the symbols:")
reader = csv.reader([Text], delimiter=',')
symbols = set(data for data in next(reader) if data)
print(symbols)
```

**Note:** the output is a set and might be empty.

Comment: I require the symbols to contain comma as well

Comment: Given the exact input you described, this code snippet will parse it in the way you wanted. Just run the example code I gave.

Answer (score 0):

I have used list to obtain the output.The input is in String form,and will accept comma-separated values.To learn about lists in Python 2.7 ,visit the documentation page.
But  as in the previous reply ,it may not work for other variable types if "" is used.
Try out this one:

```
Text=raw_input("Enter the symbols:")
Text3=[]
#empty list Text3
for x in xrange(len(Text)):
    if Text[x]!=',' and Text[x]!='"':
        Text3.append(Text[x])

    if Text[x]==',':
        if Text[x+1]=='"' and Text[x+2]==',' and Text[x+3]=='"':
            Text3.append(Text[x+2])
            x=x+4


print("REQUIRED OUTPUT:")
for j in Text3:
    print j
```

---

The output will be:

Enter the symbols:A,b,c,",",d
REQUIRED OUTPUT:
A
b
c
,

### d